# Using SumProduct With Array Formula in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a problem to use sumproduct with array formula in Google Sheet which seems workable in Excel. The formula returns only 1st array value **(E8*F8)** which what I have to do is to get total sales price from everyday.

Below is the formula I used:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(E8:J8,,column(A1:C1)*2-1)),ARRAYFORMULA(INDEX(E8:J8,,column(A1:C1)*2)))
```

Below is the table view:

[image]

- [My Spread Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rwJV3zkwLDZZXDORtBoWD1-TaSQMRkPjQQBoPpwm0gg/edit#gid=988570980)

Comment: Are you expecting a return of 92 in cell K8? It also seems to me that, while you have data in E8:J8, you will likely want to expand those columns to include more dates than just three. Is that correct? Furthermore, you have formulas happening further down the column, beginning in Row 185. I'm not sure what those are supposed to be doing. And you have totals in Row 186. Are you sure you will only ever need data in Rows 8 - 185? If so, a single array formula can produce all results for Col K.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(E8:J8, ISEVEN(COLUMN(E8:J8)))), ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(E8:J8, ISODD(COLUMN(E8:J8)))))
```

Or even simpler

```
=SUMPRODUCT({E8,G8,I8}, {F8,H8,J8})
```